# How to convert a dataframe into a csv file in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  Region   
1   a b c d 
2   b c d e g
3   a c e f g h
.
.
.
```

I want to put it into a csv file that looks like this

```
ID   a b c d e f g h
1    1 1 1 1 NA NA NA NA 
2    NA 1 1 1 1 NA 1 NA
3    1 NA 1 NA 1 1 1 1
.
.
.
```

I can convert the dataframe into a csv file, but don't know how to format it this way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data frame looks like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3,  Region = c("a b c d", "b c d e g", "a c e f g h"))

df
#>   ID      Region
#> 1  1     a b c d
#> 2  2   b c d e g
#> 3  3 a c e f g h
```

And you have a vector of all possible regions you want to define:

```r
all_regions <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
```

Then you can do:

```r
cbind(ID = df$ID,
      setNames(as.data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(df$Region, " "), 
               function(x) as.numeric(all_regions %in% x)))),
               all_names))
#>   ID a b c d e f g h
#> 1  1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> 2  2 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
#> 3  3 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reshape2

```
library(reshape2)
df2=melt(strsplit(df$Region,""))
df2=df2[df2$value!=" ",]
df2=dcast(df2,L1~value)
ifelse(is.na(df2),NA,1)

     L1  a  b c  d  e  f  g  h
[1,]  1  1  1 1  1 NA NA NA NA
[2,]  1 NA  1 1  1  1 NA  1 NA
[3,]  1  1 NA 1 NA  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is also with `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
out <- cSplit_e(df, 'Region', type = 'character', drop = TRUE, sep=" ")
names(out) <- sub("Region_", "", names(out))
```

-output

```
> out
  ID  a  b c  d  e  f  g  h
1  1  1  1 1  1 NA NA NA NA
2  2 NA  1 1  1  1 NA  1 NA
3  3  1 NA 1 NA  1  1  1  1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Region = c("a b c d", "b c d e g", "a c e f g h"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```